Firebase ESP32 Client: Getting INVALID_EMAIL Error on ESP32 PlatformIO
error code found in serial monitor
I'm working on an ESP32 project that uses an RFID reader to log attendance data to Firebase Realtime Database, in PlatformIO. I'm using the Firebase ESP Client library by Mobizt.
I keep encountering the following error messages in the Serial Monitor:
Token Info: type = ID token, status = error
Token Error: INVALID_EMAIL
Token Info: type = ID token, status = error
Token Error: bad request
Here's my code:
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Firebase_ESP_Client.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <LittleFS.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <time.h>

// Wi-Fi credentials
const char* ssid = "X";
const char* password = "X";

// Firebase API key and database URL
#define API_KEY "X"
#define DATABASE_URL "X``your text``"

// Firebase objects
FirebaseData fbdo;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseConfig config;

// RFID setup
#define RST_PIN 22
#define SS_PIN 21
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

// Web server setup
WebServer server(80);

// Time setup
const char* ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org";
const long gmtOffset_sec = -28800;
const int daylightOffset_sec = 3600;

// Variables
String uidString;
String currentTime;

// Function declarations
void handleRoot();
void handleProfiles();
void handleNotFound();
void tokenStatusCallback(TokenInfo info);
void configureTime();
String getFormattedTime();
void handleAPIRFID();
void handleAPIUpdateName();
void handleExportData();
void renderHeader(String& html, String title);
void renderFooter(String& html);
void handleFavicon();
String getTokenType(TokenInfo info);
String getTokenStatus(TokenInfo info);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin();
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();
  delay(4);

  // Initialize LittleFS
  if (!LittleFS.begin()) {
    Serial.println("An error occurred while mounting LittleFS");
  } else {
    Serial.println("LittleFS mounted successfully");
  }

  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("\nConnected to Wi-Fi");
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Configure time
  configureTime();

  // Ensure no email/password is set
  auth.user.email = "";
  auth.user.password = "";

  // Initialize Firebase Config
  config.api_key = API_KEY;
  config.database_url = DATABASE_URL;
  config.signer.anonymous = true;

  // Assign the callback function for token status
  config.token_status_callback = tokenStatusCallback;

  // Initialize Firebase
  Firebase.begin(&config, &auth);
  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);

  // Wait for authentication to complete
  Serial.println("Authenticating with Firebase...");

  unsigned long authTimeout = millis();
  const unsigned long authTimeoutDuration = 10000; // 10 seconds timeout

  while ((auth.token.uid.length() == 0) && (millis() - authTimeout < authTimeoutDuration)) {
    Firebase.ready(); // This updates the auth.token information
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  if (auth.token.uid.length() != 0) {
    Serial.println("\nFirebase authentication successful.");
    Serial.print("User UID: ");
    Serial.println(auth.token.uid.c_str());
  } else {
    Serial.println("\nFailed to authenticate with Firebase.");
    Serial.println("Check your Firebase configuration and ensure anonymous authentication is enabled.");
  }

  // Set up web server routes
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.on("/profiles", handleProfiles);
  server.on("/api/rfid", handleAPIRFID);
  server.on("/api/updateName", HTTP_POST, handleAPIUpdateName);
  server.on("/exportData", handleExportData);
  server.on("/favicon.ico", handleFavicon);
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Web server started");
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();

  // Check for new RFID cards
  if (mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    uidString = "";
    for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
      uidString.concat(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? "0" : "");
      uidString.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
    }
    uidString.toUpperCase();
    Serial.print("Card UID: ");
    Serial.println(uidString);

    // Get current time
    time_t now = time(nullptr);
    struct tm timeinfo;
    localtime_r(&now, &timeinfo);
    char timeString[25];
    strftime(timeString, sizeof(timeString), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &timeinfo);
    currentTime = String(timeString);

    // Send data to Firebase
    String basePath = "/rfid/";
    basePath.concat(uidString);

    String path_last_scanned = basePath;
    path_last_scanned.concat("/last_scanned");

    if (Firebase.RTDB.setString(&fbdo, path_last_scanned.c_str(), currentTime)) {
      Serial.println("Timestamp sent to Firebase successfully");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Failed to send timestamp to Firebase");
      Serial.println(fbdo.errorReason());
    }

    String path_uid = basePath;
    path_uid.concat("/uid");

    if (Firebase.RTDB.setString(&fbdo, path_uid.c_str(), uidString)) {
      Serial.println("UID sent to Firebase successfully");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Failed to send UID to Firebase");
      Serial.println(fbdo.errorReason());
    }

    mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
    mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();
  }
}

// Web server handlers
void handleRoot() {
  String html;
  renderHeader(html, "RFID Attendance Tracker");

  html.concat("<div class='container'>");
  html.concat("<h1>Welcome to the RFID Attendance Tracker</h1>");
  html.concat("<p>Use your RFID card to register your attendance.</p>");
  html.concat("<p>Current Time: ");
  html.concat(getFormattedTime());
  html.concat("</p>");
  html.concat("</div>");

  renderFooter(html);
  server.send(200, "text/html", html);
}

void handleProfiles() {
  // Retrieve data from Firebase
  if (Firebase.RTDB.getJSON(&fbdo, "/rfid")) {
    FirebaseJson& json = fbdo.jsonObject();
    String jsonStr;
    json.toString(jsonStr, true);

    // Parse JSON data
    DynamicJsonDocument doc(8192);
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, jsonStr);

    if (error) {
      Serial.print("deserializeJson() failed: ");
      Serial.println(error.c_str());
      server.send(500, "text/plain", "Failed to parse data");
      return;
    }

    // Generate HTML page
    String html;
    renderHeader(html, "Profiles");

    html.concat("<div class='container'>");
    html.concat("<h1>Scanned Cards</h1>");
    html.concat("<table><tr><th>UID</th><th>Last Scanned</th></tr>");

    for (JsonPair kv : doc.as<JsonObject>()) {
      String uid = kv.value()["uid"].as<String>();
      String lastScanned = kv.value()["last_scanned"].as<String>();
      html.concat("<tr><td>");
      html.concat(uid);
      html.concat("</td>");
      html.concat("<td>");
      html.concat(lastScanned);
      html.concat("</td></tr>");
    }

    html.concat("</table></div>");

    renderFooter(html);
    server.send(200, "text/html", html);
  } else {
    server.send(500, "text/plain", "Failed to retrieve data from Firebase");
    Serial.println(fbdo.errorReason());
  }
}

void handleAPIRFID() {
  // This handler can be used to provide RFID data as JSON
  if (Firebase.RTDB.getJSON(&fbdo, "/rfid")) {
    FirebaseJson& json = fbdo.jsonObject();
    String jsonStr;
    json.toString(jsonStr, true);
    server.send(200, "application/json", jsonStr);
  } else {
    server.send(500, "text/plain", "Failed to retrieve data from Firebase");
    Serial.println(fbdo.errorReason());
  }
}

void handleAPIUpdateName() {
  if (server.method() != HTTP_POST) {
    server.send(405, "text/plain", "Method Not Allowed");
    return;
  }

  // Parse the JSON body
  StaticJsonDocument<512> doc;
  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, server.arg("plain"));
  if (error) {
    Serial.print("Failed to parse updateName request: ");
    Serial.println(error.c_str());
    server.send(400, "application/json", "{\"success\":false, \"message\":\"Invalid JSON\"}");
    return;
  }

  String uid = doc["uid"].as<String>();
  String name = doc["name"].as<String>();

  if (uid.isEmpty()) {
    server.send(400, "application/json", "{\"success\":false, \"message\":\"UID is required\"}");
    return;
  }

  // Update name in Firebase
  String basePath = "/rfid/";
  basePath.concat(uid);
  basePath.concat("/name");

  if (Firebase.RTDB.setString(&fbdo, basePath.c_str(), name)) {
    server.send(200, "application/json", "{\"success\":true}");
  } else {
    server.send(500, "application/json", "{\"success\":false, \"message\":\"Failed to update name in Firebase\"}");
    Serial.println(fbdo.errorReason());
  }
}

void handleExportData() {
  // Export data as JSON
  if (Firebase.RTDB.getJSON(&fbdo, "/rfid")) {
    FirebaseJson& json = fbdo.jsonObject();
    String jsonStr;
    json.toString(jsonStr, true);
    server.sendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"rfid_data.json\"");
    server.send(200, "application/json", jsonStr);
  } else {
    server.send(500, "text/plain", "Failed to retrieve data from Firebase");
    Serial.println(fbdo.errorReason());
  }
}

void handleFavicon() {
  server.send(204, "image/x-icon", ""); // No Content
}

void handleNotFound() {
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "404: Not Found");
}

// Helper functions

void renderHeader(String& html, String title) {
  html.concat("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>");
  html.concat("<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>");
  html.concat("<title>");
  html.concat(title);
  html.concat("</title>");
  html.concat("<style>");
  html.concat("body { font-family: Arial; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #f2f2f2; }");
  html.concat("nav { background-color: #333; color: #fff; padding: 10px; }");
  html.concat("nav a { color: #fff; margin-right: 15px; text-decoration: none; }");
  html.concat(".container { padding: 20px; }");
  html.concat("table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }");
  html.concat("th, td { border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px; }");
  html.concat("th { background-color: #333; color: white; }");
  html.concat("</style></head><body>");
  html.concat("<nav><a href='/'>Home</a><a href='/profiles'>Profiles</a><a href='/exportData'>Export Data</a></nav>");
}

void renderFooter(String& html) {
  html.concat("</body></html>");
}

void configureTime() {
  configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer);
  Serial.println("Configuring time...");

  struct tm timeinfo;
  int retries = 0;
  const int maxRetries = 10;
  while (!getLocalTime(&timeinfo) && retries < maxRetries) {
    Serial.println("Waiting for time synchronization...");
    delay(1000);
    retries++;
  }

  if (retries < maxRetries) {
    Serial.printf("Time configured: %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
                  timeinfo.tm_year + 1900,
                  timeinfo.tm_mon + 1,
                  timeinfo.tm_mday,
                  timeinfo.tm_hour,
                  timeinfo.tm_min,
                  timeinfo.tm_sec);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
  }
}

String getFormattedTime() {
  struct tm timeinfo;
  if (!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)) {
    return "Time not available";
  }
  char buffer[25];
  strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &timeinfo);
  return String(buffer);
}

// Token status callback function
void tokenStatusCallback(TokenInfo info) {
  Serial.printf("Token Info: type = %s, status = %s\n", getTokenType(info).c_str(), getTokenStatus(info).c_str());
  if (info.status == token_status_error) {
    Serial.printf("Token Error: %s\n", info.error.message.c_str());
  }
}

String getTokenType(TokenInfo info) {
  switch (info.type) {
    case token_type_undefined:
      return "undefined";
    case token_type_legacy_token:
      return "legacy token";
    case token_type_id_token:
      return "ID token";
    case token_type_custom_token:
      return "custom token";
    case token_type_oauth2_access_token:
      return "OAuth2 access token";
    default:
      return "unknown";
  }
}

String getTokenStatus(TokenInfo info) {
  switch (info.status) {
    case token_status_uninitialized:
      return "uninitialized";
    case token_status_on_signing:
      return "on signing";
    case token_status_on_request:
      return "on request";
    case token_status_on_refresh:
      return "on refresh";
    case token_status_ready:
      return "ready";
    case token_status_error:
      return "error";
    default:
      return "unknown";
  }
}

Fixes Attempted:
Verified that Anonymous Authentication is enabled in Firebase Console under Authentication > Sign-in method.
Double-checked my API key and database URL to ensure they are correct.
Ensured that auth.user.email and auth.user.password are not set anywhere in my code.
Updated the Firebase ESP Client library to the latest version (I'm using version 4.3.1).
Waited for authentication to complete before interacting with Firebase, using a loop to check Firebase.ready().
Erased the ESP32 flash memory to clear any old credentials.
Despite these efforts, the INVALID_EMAIL error persists.
